# need a help for the error Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard, sfdoctrineguard

i am develping a project using symfony1.4.16 and Doctrine and for authentication i am using sfDoctrineGuardPlugin. In my localhost it was working fine. when i moved my project on a shared host i am getting this error(`Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"`) while login. when i search for this error in Google many people are recommending for `delete all SFGuard Forms from lib/form/doctrine/base and reinstalling the plugin`.How do i reinstall it on my sharedhost? what are the procedure should i take for uninstalling it on my sharedhost? whether i need to reinstall it in my localhost and upload it to my server or for should i use the command `symfony plugin:uninstall sfDoctrineGuardPlugin` or simply delete the files in `lib/form/doctrine/base` and upload it again to my server.The other modules which is not related to sfDoctrineGuardPlugin is working fine.Any one please help me...

**More Information**

when i login i am getting the error `Unknown record property / related component "permissions" on "sfGuardUser"` and when i refresh the page error is gone and i am redirecting to home page. In home page i have links for

1. add user,group,permission
2. edit user,group,permission
3. list user,group,permission 
   when i am trying to access add or edit portion i am getting error like this. List and delete portion is working fine

   here i am attaching the screen shots of error and error log.

   1.[error page](http://i44.tinypic.com/23w5oqf.jpg)
   2.[error log](http://i41.tinypic.com/sxi13d.jpg)

**

### BaseSfGuardUser.class

**

```
<?php
// Connection Component Binding
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->bindComponent('SfGuardUser', 'doctrine');

/**
 * BaseSfGuardUser
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $first_name
 * @property string $last_name
 * @property string $email_address
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $algorithm
 * @property string $salt
 * @property string $password
 * @property integer $is_active
 * @property integer $is_super_admin
 * @property timestamp $last_login
 * @property timestamp $created_at
 * @property timestamp $updated_at
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $SfGuardForgotPassword
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $SfGuardRememberKey
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $SfGuardUserGroup
 * @property Doctrine_Collection $SfGuardUserPermission
 * 
 * @method integer             getId()                    Returns the current record's "id" value
 * @method string              getFirstName()             Returns the current record's "first_name" value
 * @method string              getLastName()              Returns the current record's "last_name" value
 * @method string              getEmailAddress()          Returns the current record's "email_address" value
 * @method string              getUsername()              Returns the current record's "username" value
 * @method string              getAlgorithm()             Returns the current record's "algorithm" value
 * @method string              getSalt()                  Returns the current record's "salt" value
 * @method string              getPassword()              Returns the current record's "password" value
 * @method integer             getIsActive()              Returns the current record's "is_active" value
 * @method integer             getIsSuperAdmin()          Returns the current record's "is_super_admin" value
 * @method timestamp           getLastLogin()             Returns the current record's "last_login" value
 * @method timestamp           getCreatedAt()             Returns the current record's "created_at" value
 * @method timestamp           getUpdatedAt()             Returns the current record's "updated_at" value
 * @method Doctrine_Collection getSfGuardForgotPassword() Returns the current record's "SfGuardForgotPassword" collection
 * @method Doctrine_Collection getSfGuardRememberKey()    Returns the current record's "SfGuardRememberKey" collection
 * @method Doctrine_Collection getSfGuardUserGroup()      Returns the current record's "SfGuardUserGroup" collection
 * @method Doctrine_Collection getSfGuardUserPermission() Returns the current record's "SfGuardUserPermission" collection
 * @method SfGuardUser         setId()                    Sets the current record's "id" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setFirstName()             Sets the current record's "first_name" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setLastName()              Sets the current record's "last_name" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setEmailAddress()          Sets the current record's "email_address" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setUsername()              Sets the current record's "username" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setAlgorithm()             Sets the current record's "algorithm" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setSalt()                  Sets the current record's "salt" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setPassword()              Sets the current record's "password" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setIsActive()              Sets the current record's "is_active" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setIsSuperAdmin()          Sets the current record's "is_super_admin" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setLastLogin()             Sets the current record's "last_login" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setCreatedAt()             Sets the current record's "created_at" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setUpdatedAt()             Sets the current record's "updated_at" value
 * @method SfGuardUser         setSfGuardForgotPassword() Sets the current record's "SfGuardForgotPassword" collection
 * @method SfGuardUser         setSfGuardRememberKey()    Sets the current record's "SfGuardRememberKey" collection
 * @method SfGuardUser         setSfGuardUserGroup()      Sets the current record's "SfGuardUserGroup" collection
 * @method SfGuardUser         setSfGuardUserPermission() Sets the current record's "SfGuardUserPermission" collection
 * 
 * @package    ticketsystem
 * @subpackage model
 * @author     Your name here
 * @version    SVN: $Id: Builder.php 7490 2010-03-29 19:53:27Z jwage $
 */
abstract class BaseSfGuardUser extends sfDoctrineRecord
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('sf_guard_user');
        $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 8, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => true,
             'autoincrement' => true,
             'length' => 8,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('first_name', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 255,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('last_name', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 255,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('email_address', 'string', 255, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 255,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('username', 'string', 128, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 128,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('algorithm', 'string', 128, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => 'sha1',
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 128,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('salt', 'string', 128, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 128,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('password', 'string', 128, array(
             'type' => 'string',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 128,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('is_active', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '1',
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 1,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('is_super_admin', 'integer', 1, array(
             'type' => 'integer',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'default' => '0',
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 1,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('last_login', 'timestamp', 25, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => false,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 25,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('created_at', 'timestamp', 25, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 25,
             ));
        $this->hasColumn('updated_at', 'timestamp', 25, array(
             'type' => 'timestamp',
             'fixed' => 0,
             'unsigned' => false,
             'primary' => false,
             'notnull' => true,
             'autoincrement' => false,
             'length' => 25,
             ));
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->hasMany('SfGuardForgotPassword', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id',
             'onDelete' => 'CASCADE'));

        $this->hasMany('SfGuardRememberKey', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id',
             'onDelete' => 'CASCADE'));

        $this->hasMany('SfGuardUserGroup', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id',
             'onDelete' => 'CASCADE'));

        $this->hasMany('SfGuardUserPermission', array(
             'local' => 'id',
             'foreign' => 'user_id',
             'onDelete' => 'CASCADE'));
    }
}
```

**

### BaseSfGuardUserForm.class

**

```
<?php

/**
 * SfGuardUser form base class.
 *
 * @method SfGuardUser getObject() Returns the current form's model object
 *
 * @package    ticketsystem
 * @subpackage form
 * @author     Your name here
 * @version    SVN: $Id: sfDoctrineFormGeneratedTemplate.php 29553 2010-05-20 14:33:00Z Kris.Wallsmith $
 */
abstract class BaseSfGuardUserForm extends BaseFormDoctrine
{
  public function setup()
  {
    $this->setWidgets(array(
      'id'               => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
      'first_name'       => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'last_name'        => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'email_address'    => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'username'         => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'algorithm'        => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'salt'             => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'password'         => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
      'is_active'        => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
      'is_super_admin'   => new sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox(),
      'last_login'       => new sfWidgetFormDateTime(),
      'created_at'       => new sfWidgetFormDateTime(),
      'updated_at'       => new sfWidgetFormDateTime(),
      'groups_list'      => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'sfGuardGroup')),
      'permissions_list' => new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'sfGuardPermission')),
    ));

    $this->setValidators(array(
      'id'               => new sfValidatorChoice(array('choices' => array($this->getObject()->get('id')), 'empty_value' => $this->getObject()->get('id'), 'required' => false)),
      'first_name'       => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 255, 'required' => false)),
      'last_name'        => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 255, 'required' => false)),
      'email_address'    => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 255)),
      'username'         => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 128)),
      'algorithm'        => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 128, 'required' => false)),
      'salt'             => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 128, 'required' => false)),
      'password'         => new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 128, 'required' => false)),
      'is_active'        => new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false)),
      'is_super_admin'   => new sfValidatorBoolean(array('required' => false)),
      'last_login'       => new sfValidatorDateTime(array('required' => false)),
      'created_at'       => new sfValidatorDateTime(),
      'updated_at'       => new sfValidatorDateTime(),
      'groups_list'      => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'sfGuardGroup', 'required' => false)),
      'permissions_list' => new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'sfGuardPermission', 'required' => false)),
    ));

    $this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
      new sfValidatorAnd(array(
        new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model' => 'SfGuardUser', 'column' => array('email_address'))),
        new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array('model' => 'SfGuardUser', 'column' => array('username'))),
      ))
    );

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('sf_guard_user[%s]');

    $this->errorSchema = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($this->validatorSchema);

    $this->setupInheritance();

    parent::setup();
  }

  public function getModelName()
  {
    return 'SfGuardUser';
  }

  public function updateDefaultsFromObject()
  {
    parent::updateDefaultsFromObject();

    if (isset($this->widgetSchema['groups_list']))
    {
      $this->setDefault('groups_list', $this->object->Groups->getPrimaryKeys());
    }

    if (isset($this->widgetSchema['permissions_list']))
    {
      $this->setDefault('permissions_list', $this->object->Permissions->getPrimaryKeys());
    }

  }

  protected function doSave($con = null)
  {
    $this->saveGroupsList($con);
    $this->savePermissionsList($con);

    parent::doSave($con);
  }

  public function saveGroupsList($con = null)
  {
    if (!$this->isValid())
    {
      throw $this->getErrorSchema();
    }

    if (!isset($this->widgetSchema['groups_list']))
    {
      // somebody has unset this widget
      return;
    }

    if (null === $con)
    {
      $con = $this->getConnection();
    }

    $existing = $this->object->Groups->getPrimaryKeys();
    $values = $this->getValue('groups_list');
    if (!is_array($values))
    {
      $values = array();
    }

    $unlink = array_diff($existing, $values);
    if (count($unlink))
    {
      $this->object->unlink('Groups', array_values($unlink));
    }

    $link = array_diff($values, $existing);
    if (count($link))
    {
      $this->object->link('Groups', array_values($link));
    }
  }

  public function savePermissionsList($con = null)
  {
    if (!$this->isValid())
    {
      throw $this->getErrorSchema();
    }

    if (!isset($this->widgetSchema['permissions_list']))
    {
      // somebody has unset this widget
      return;
    }

    if (null === $con)
    {
      $con = $this->getConnection();
    }

    $existing = $this->object->Permissions->getPrimaryKeys();
    $values = $this->getValue('permissions_list');
    if (!is_array($values))
    {
      $values = array();
    }

    $unlink = array_diff($existing, $values);
    if (count($unlink))
    {
      $this->object->unlink('Permissions', array_values($unlink));
    }

    $link = array_diff($values, $existing);
    if (count($link))
    {
      $this->object->link('Permissions', array_values($link));
    }
  }

}
```

here i am attaching my database schema too

**

### schema.yml

**

```
SfGuardForgotPassword:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_forgot_password
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    unique_key:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    expires_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
SfGuardGroup:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_group
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    description:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardGroupPermission:
      local: id
      foreign: group_id
      type: many
    SfGuardUserGroup:
      local: id
      foreign: group_id
      type: many
SfGuardGroupPermission:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_group_permission
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    permission_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardGroup:
      local: group_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    SfGuardPermission:
      local: permission_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
SfGuardPermission:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_permission
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    description:
      type: string()
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardGroupPermission:
      local: id
      foreign: permission_id
      type: many
    SfGuardUserPermission:
      local: id
      foreign: permission_id
      type: many
SfGuardRememberKey:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_remember_key
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    remember_key:
      type: string(32)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    ip_address:
      type: string(50)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false

      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
SfGuardUser:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
    first_name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    last_name:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    email_address:
      type: string(255)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    username:
      type: string(128)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    algorithm:
      type: string(128)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: sha1
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    salt:
      type: string(128)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    password:
      type: string(128)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    is_active:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '1'
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    is_super_admin:
      type: integer(1)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      default: '0'
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    last_login:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardForgotPassword:
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      type: many
    SfGuardRememberKey:
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      type: many
    SfGuardUserGroup:
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      type: many
    SfGuardUserPermission:
      local: id
      foreign: user_id
      type: many
SfGuardUserGroup:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user_group
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    group_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardGroup:
      local: group_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    SfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
SfGuardUserPermission:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sf_guard_user_permission
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    permission_id:
      type: integer(8)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: false
    created_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
    updated_at:
      type: timestamp(25)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    SfGuardPermission:
      local: permission_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
    SfGuardUser:
      local: user_id
      foreign: id
      type: one
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace to debug

Comment: @Mikhail i have added more information and attached 2 screenshots.

Comment: Provide BasesfGuardUser class too

Comment: @ Mikhail i have added BasesfGuardUser class

Comment: Ok, as you can see your BaseSfGuardUser class doesn't contain a Permissions relation. I believe that all of you need it's a rebuild you models. See below answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. clear symfony cache
2. remove base models of the sfDoctrineGuardPlugin:

`lib/model/doctrine/sfDoctrineGuardPLugin/base/`

1. rebuild your models using command line:

`$ php symfony doctrine:build-model`

1. rebuild your DB using command line

`$ php symfony doctrine:build-sql

$ php symfony doctrine:insert-sql`

Answer (score 2):

During I server migration, I was seeing this same error for a different reason.  The new server was running PHP 7.0, but I got it working by downgrading to PHP 5.6 (following the [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761713/how-can-i-downgrade-from-php-7-to-php-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04)).

Comment: Doctrine 1.2 is incompatible with PHP 7, due to "Changes to the handling of indirect variables, properties, and methods"  https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect

This exact error (probably there are much more when used with 7) comes from doctrine/Doctrine/Collection.php class (line 463), where exisiting code:
`$record->$relation['alias'] = $this->reference;`
for PHP 7 should be:
`$record->{$relation['alias']} = $this->reference;`
and without that is interpreted as:
`($record->$relation)['alias'] = $this->reference;`